# A weed that looks like a flower but comes out like a dandilion

Tags: identification, weeds

There is a weed in my garden, and the bud looks like a flower, but when it comes out it is seeds like a [Taraxacum Erythrospermum](https://www.google.com/search?q=taraxacum%20erythrospermum&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS908US908&sxsrf=ALeKk02p3DzaLcPqFuvOA4rXGnoWZOHxNA%3A1626102245497&ei=5VnsYPLVHcPl5NoPseSMgAE&gs_ssp=eJzj4tLP1TcwLzapiC80YPSSKEksSqxITC7NVUgtqizJKMovLkgtyi3NBQD0cA3F&oq=dandelion&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYCTIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQsAMQQzINCC4QsAMQyAMQQxCTAjIKCC4QsAMQyAMQQzIKCC4QsAMQyAMQQzIKCC4QsAMQyAMQQzIKCC4QsAMQyAMQQzIKCC4QsAMQyAMQQ0oFCDgSATFKBAhBGABQAFgAYJ0naAFwAngAgAFmiAFmkgEDMC4xmAEAqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBD8ABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) plant.

Pictures:
[image: 2]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

[image: 6]

[image: 7]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [Common Groundsel](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Common_Groundsel-branching.jpg) (*Senecio vulgaris*). It's found pretty much throughout the eastern US, is a non-native, and is considered a weed.